# Where can I investigate session-only spontaneous mouse failure?

Tags: linux, mouse, touchpad, lenovo-laptop, xubuntu

On my Lenovo S340 Ideapad with Xubuntu 19.10, I'm having a strange issue with my touchpad, apparently a 'MSFT0001:02 04F3:304B Touchpad' using a Synaptics driver. For no reason that I can find, the touchpad sometimes loses its ability to move the mouse. Despite this:

- The touchpad can still left-click and right-click.
- The keyboard works as normal.
- The mouse works fine on the lock screen (reached via the terminal); issues only return after an unlock.
- Logging out and back in fixes the problem.
- No method of disabling and renabling the touchpad that I know of fixes the problem. For example, I've had no success with `sudo modprobe psmouse`, `sudo modprobe -r psmouse`, or the otherwise-working Fn+F6.
- Of what is listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127884/touchpad-stops-working-after-suspend-on-lenovo-t520), I have not tried `sudo rmmod psmouse` or installing the Synaptics program.
- Gestures no longer work.
- I know of no gestures that could cause this.

Where can I investigate this problem further? Is there a less extreme temporary solution than logging out? So far, I have only noticed that [I might have ACPI issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/1217974/824054).

Update: The past two times that my mouse has failed, it has been through plugging in my USB headphone and turning it on. This doesn't always happen, but it's the only causal link that I've found.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of hardware problem. Or overload (the machine just can't keep up with mouse pointer movement/display).

Comment: @vonbrand So you're suggesting killing tasks as a solution?

Comment: Sounds like [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127884/touchpad-stops-working-after-suspend-on-lenovo-t520). Try if the solutions there work for you. This is probably a driver problem. What exactly is your touchpad model?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, I really should've mentioned the specs. Edited to reflect, with a list of what I have and have not tried form your link.

Comment: Without a better driver the most you can do are workarounds. Maybe try `sudo modprobe -r i2c_hid && sudo i2c_hid`.

Comment: @harrymc Is there a way to get a better driver? I couldn't find the version number for my current one.

Comment: Check first [Which driver is handling my touchpad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131432/which-driver-is-handling-my-touchpad).

Comment: @harrymc I now suspect that you've rightly guessed that it's i2c_hid or something related to it, but I'm admittedly more confused now than I was earlier.  I can't seem to pinpoint what firmware is doing what. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1202561/824054) seems relevant.

Comment: Questions: Have you fully updated your system, kernel and everything? Does my above `modprobe` line help to unblock the situation?

Comment: @harrymc ```sudo modprobe -r i2c_hid``` turns off my touchpad, seemingly preventing even clicking, and ```sudo modprobe i2c_hid``` turns it back on. I've yet to have the spontaneous freeze again, so I don't yet know if this fixed the problem. As for updates, ```sudo apt-get update``` says I'm up to date.

Comment: It would be funny if running these commands fixes the problem for the current session. It would also be easy then to have it run after boot.

Comment: @harrymc If it did fix the problem for a session, would this help towards finding out what's broke and therefore a permanent fix?

Comment: I doubt it, but first wait and see.

Comment: Any news about the problem?

Comment: @harrymc None, it's not happened again yet.

Comment: Should I put up an answer with the `modprobe` line?

Comment: @harrymc I'd not accept it yet, but it can't hurt to get this out of the comments.

Comment: @harrymc [I might have ACPI issues.](https://askubuntu.com/q/1217974/824054)

Comment: Do you have messages about "duplicate WMI GUID"? I must say that I disagree with the notion of a computer manufactured for Windows for which Linux can hardly "duplicate" the BIOS calls. The only remedy by that guy is to replace massively the drivers, which has its own dangers.

Comment: @harrymc Yes. In fact, they and the dmesg output should be in that linked question. ```dmesg | grep WMI``` gives ```[    1.065700] acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)``` and
```[    1.065740] acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)```.

Comment: Analyzing this message took too much space, so I put it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command was effective for the last couple of days for the poster:

```
sudo modprobe -r i2c_hid && sudo i2c_hid
```

Waiting for more feedback from the poster as to how long it will continue on working.

---

Regarding the errors of "duplicate WMI GUID":
Your system might really have WMI devices with duplicate GUID ids.

This
[bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806437)
says:

> WMI is not really a part of ACPI specification, but a Microsoft specific standard.

Strangely enough, in that bug report one finds the same
[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217974/why-would-a-suspend-issue-exist-on-an-installed-os-but-not-its-live-disk)
link you found as the only claim for it causing suspend problems.

Looking in the Linux sources for
[wmi.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/x86/wmi.c),
I found this comment:

```
 * Because we historically didn't track the relationship  
 * between GUIDs and ACPI nodes, we don't know whether  
 * we need to suppress GUIDs that are unique on a  
 * given node but duplicated across nodes.
```

Or another:

```
 * Some WMI devices, like those for nVidia hooks, have a  
 * duplicate GUID. It's not clear what we should do in this  
 * case yet, so for now, we'll just ignore the duplicate  
 * for device creation.
```

The code around the last message just ignores such devices.
So if all your devices work well before the problem,
then I don't think that this is the cause for it.

I have not found any Linux tools for listing WMI GUIDs,
only in Windows, so I can't tell how to find which one of your devices
is presenting duplicate WMI GUIDs.

Comment: I just got the problem again. The line you've used throws the error ```sudo: i2c_hid: command not found```. However, using ```sudo modprobe i2c_hid
``` after that has fixed the problem.

Comment: This is then a good workaround but not a solution. It's too consistent to be hardware, so is probably a driver problem. I think the most you can do is keep everything updated. You could also open a bug report on the Xubuntu forum.

Comment: Update: The past two times that my mouse has failed, it has been through plugging in my USB mic and turning it on. This doesn't always happen, but it's the only causal link that I've found.

Comment: It's possible that if you a device with duplicate WMI GUID, this causes one of the duplicates to be lost. I have found a couple of WMI implementations on Linux. You could try [Wmic-linux](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Wmic-linux) or [WMI from Linux and Python](https://adamtheautomator.com/query-wmi-linux-python/).

Comment: Those looks so old that I wouldn't be surprised if they've already been implemented.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it if the final decision was to ignore WMI.